# TradingView Strategy Tester - Can I change the colour of entry/exit arrows on the chart

Tags: colors, pine-script, arrows

if anyone can help me.
When testing a strategy in TradingView, is there any way to change the colour of entry and exit arrows on the chart?
For example, I want to mark exits with a profit and with a loss by different colours (Currently, it's purple for all exits.)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not currently possible. We have a suggestion in to allow it, but no ETA on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!